# How to define a global struct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I want struct which should be in any controller or in any class ...

Anyone have idea about this ?

Code :

```
typedef struct Student{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *name;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *lastName;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *firstName;
}student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your struct visible everywhere in the project, import your header file where you defined the structure into `your_project_name_Prefix.pch`

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Pashkov, it works very well.... But is there any other way (i.e. Extern keyword) or like this.....

Comment: the extern keyword really exists but that doesn`t make the struct available for all classes, so either you use the prefix file or you add the file where you defined the struct to the prefix file.

Comment: @kishan94 Better to use class, that will represent student's model in this case. Imagine, you need to sort array of your students by name. How will you do this with a struct?